# A Jquery function to increase body margin on Nav reveal

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this piece of JQ to animate the reveal of the side nav-bar on hover over the menu Icon. 
Right now I've got the nav-bar .8 opacity and z-indexed to appear over the body.

What I'm trying to do is to get the main body to animate an increase of left margin to make room for the nav-bar as it reveals, rather than it appearing over the top. Of course I want the script to reverse the animation on mouseLeave. Hope that makes sense.
Anyone have an idea what I can add to the code to get the desired result?

http://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/06ysqr1r/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#burger').hover( function() { $('nav').slideDown(1000); });
});
    $(function() {
      $('nav').mouseleave( function() { 
$('nav').slideUp(1000); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you put this into js fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/06ysqr1r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to add a left margin to the `#about` div. Here's a JSFiddle showing how this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkLL6yab/1/

A few notes:

1. You can attach both events inside of a single anonymous function passed to the `$` method, instead of having two separate instances of `$(function() {...})`
2. `hover` might not be the best option for opening the menu, as it's usually intended to bind both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. I suggest just using `mouseenter` for your use-case.

I've made these two updates in the JSFiddle link above.

It does look a bit weird to have the menu showing over the content as it slides down. You can take advantage of the callback arguments provided by the `slideUp`, `slideDown`, and `animate` methods in order to avoid this. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/70p1dLy6/1/

Answer (score 0):

you could even do all of this with CSS only. Let's go with the js route, though: first wrap non-nav body contents in an absolutely positioned wrapper.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/06ysqr1r/21/)

[image]

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="ab" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="po" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="co" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="bl" href="#blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper"> <!-- here -->
        <div id="burger">
            <img src="https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/134216/hamburger_lines_menu_icon" alt="Munu">
        </div>
```

css

```
div.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transition: left 200ms ease;
}
body {
    position: relative; // relative class
    font: normal 1.1em/1.5 sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}
```

js

```
$(function () {
    var navWidth = $('nav').outerWidth(true);
    $('#burger, nav').hover(function () {
        $('nav').stop().slideDown(200);
        $('div.wrapper').css({
            'left': navWidth + 'px',
        });
    }, function () {
        $('nav').stop().slideUp(200);
        $('div.wrapper').css({
            'left': '0px',
        });
    })
});
```